# Visual studio add watch to object property

Tags: visual-studio-2010, properties, watch

In visual studio 2010 if I add a watch to a property of an object, by right clicking the property and going to add watch, in the watch window it just adds the property name instead of object.property name and hence it will also show "xxx does not exist in the current context".

Am I going about this the wrong way or is this a bug in visual studio?

I can get the watch to work by typing object.property manually in the watch window but it seems to defeat the whole purpose of that menu item being there.

Comment: There are few odds for VS to ever get that close to accurate.  Select first.

Comment: Make it blue first, click and drag the mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you should select the object.property completely and then add it to the watch window.